# ASP.NET MVC - ajax call to server side for pdf files?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, file

I am trying to make an Ajax call to my app's controller to get some PDF files as follows:

```
function AjaxCallImages(URL) {

   var result = $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: URL,
       success: SuccessFunctionImages,
       error: ErrorFunction
    });

    return result;
}
```

On the server side of my web app (in the model), I am reading files from a remote server:

```
public static List<byte[]> GetFiles()
{
     List<byte[]> files = new List<byte[]>();
     string uri = @"\\REMOTER_SERVER_IP\Users\Public\myfolder";
     string[] filesInfo = Directory.GetFiles(uri);
     foreach (string fPath in filesInfo)
     {
        string fileName = MYPATH;
        using (var webClient = new WebClientNoKeepAlive())
        {
            byte[] filedata = webClient.DownloadData(fPath);

            files.Add(filedata);
         }
     }
     return files;
}
```

and the result (List) is sent back to the controller in the ajax call.

What I receive is arrays of strings.

I need to show these pdf files in the browser but I am not sure how could I do this and if using Ajax is a good idea. But since I want to show images without reloading the page, I opted for Ajax. It there a good solution to do so? I would appreciate if someone kindly guide me about that. Thank you

Comment: With ajax you can't, I think.

Comment: you could put the files into a single zip file and download that.

Comment: Or, you can bring back a list of Id's from the server linked to your files, and in the ajax, just call a partialView that returns the files one by one, that way you can view multiple files at once